# SEQUELIZE not auto incrementing id with inserting a row?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

**issue:** currently I can insert a row in the database table using SEQUELIZE and node api post method.

However, if I try sending a new project object using postman, the program just updates the first row with id 1!

API.js

```
router.post("/project", async (req, res, next) => {

  if (req.body) {
    // validate req.body then...

    const project = await ProjectService.saveProject(req.body);

    res.status(200).send(project);
  }
});
```

ProjectService.js

```
const { Projects, sequelize } = require("../models/ProjectModel");

class ProjectService {

  static async saveProject(project) {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true }); // creates the Projects row (if doesn't exist in db)
    const projectBuilt = Projects.build({
      CompanyID: project.CompanyID,
      Name: project.Name,
      ContextID: project.ContextID,
      Latitude: project.Latitude,
      Longitude: project.Longitude,
      StateID: project.StateID,
      RegionID: project.RegionID,
      RadiusCovered: project.RadiusCovered,
      SubRegionID: project.SubRegionID,
      CommonWealth: project.CommonWealth
    });

    await projectBuilt.save();
    console.log("\n\n Project Saved to database!");

    return { project: projectBuilt };
  }
}

module.exports = ProjectService;
```

ProjectModel.js

```
// var database = require("./loaders/database"); /* Database depedency */

const { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize("new_rps", "root", "password", {
  dialect: "mysql",
  dialectOptions: {
    // Your mysql2 options here
  }
});

const Projects = sequelize.define(
  "Projects",
  {
    CompanyID: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    Name: DataTypes.TEXT,
    ContextID: DataTypes.TEXT,
    Latitude: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    Longitude: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    StateID: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    RegionID: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    RadiusCovered: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    SubRegionID: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    CommonWealth: DataTypes.INTEGER
  },
  {
    tableName: "Projects"
  }
);

module.exports = {
  Projects,
  sequelize
};
```

**What I want: To add a new row instead of updating the first row with id 1. In the database, I have auto increment on the table too fyi! Any ideas?**

**UPDATED MODEL** STILL NOT WORKING

```
const Projects = sequelize.define(
  "Projects",
  {
    ID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    CompanyID: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    Name: DataTypes.TEXT,
    ContextID: DataTypes.TEXT,
    Latitude: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    Longitude: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    StateID: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    RegionID: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    RadiusCovered: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    SubRegionID: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    CommonWealth: DataTypes.INTEGER
  },
  {
    tableName: "Projects"
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your model definition the id column with the following options.
This way sequelize will know to generate the id of the inserted row.

```js
id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
}
```

Comment: I have done this, no luck. Pls check the updated model in the question part. any ideas?

Comment: please help? :/

Comment: Huh. the problem was with this line I commented out, it works:     // await sequelize.sync({ force: true }); // creates the Projects row (if doesn't exist in db)